# equality test for MIDI file header chunk

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a piece of code to test the validity of header chunk in a MIDI file, (only first 4 bites included so far), but it returns False and I can't understand why.
below is my code:

```
header="b'MThd'" #i tried this line without b' as well

with open('file.mid', 'rb') as file:
    print(file.read(4) == header)
```

Comment: Don't put additional quotes around the bytes object. Use `header = b'MThd'` instead.

Comment: thank you MattDMo. you were right and it works. only could you please tell me what is that b suffix? does it mean the object is being read in binary? i searched for it alot but didn't find anything related.

Comment: It's a [bytes object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes-objects) literal.